# shell_exec function always giving null value when try to create video thumbnail using ffmpeg codeginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, shell-exec, video-thumbnails

I am working in codeigniter. I had facing problem in creating thumbnail image for video files.if any can give me the code for generating a thumbnail image for the video files using codeigniter. I had generated a thumbnail image for the image using the below code using ffmpeg extension.It always giving null values.

```
function upload_video()
{
    $files = $_FILES;
    $cpt = count($_FILES['video']['name']);
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++)
    {
        $_FILES['video']['name']= $files['video']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['video']['type']= $files['video']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['video']['tmp_name']= $files['video']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['video']['error']= $files['video']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['video']['size']= $files['video']['size'][$i]; 

        $this->load->library('upload', $this->upload_options());

        $this->upload->initialize($this->upload_options());

        $this->upload->do_upload('video');

        $files_uploaded=$this->upload->data();

        $f_name=$files_uploaded['client_name'];
        $directory_path=$files_uploaded['file_path'];
        $directory_path_full=$files_uploaded['full_path']; 

    $out=shell_exec("ffmpeg -y -i C:\xampp\htdocs\photo24\video\140902video-2012-07-05-02-29-27.mp4 -f mjpeg -ss 10 -vframes 1 160x120 C:/xampp/htdocs/photo24/video/thumb/mythumb.jpg 2>&1");

    file_put_contents($dir.'cmd.log', $cmd); // to debug
    //var_dump($out);

        echo $file_array_data = $this->upload->display_errors();
        $this->user_model->add_video($files_uploaded);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

php.net says :

This function can return NULL both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. exec() should be used when access to the program exit code is required. 
if you want to use "exec()" fucntions don't forget to use like:

```
unset($output);
exec("ls -l",$output);
```

Comment: Also seems like you are doing a background proccess so php doesn't wait the line to finish the end part of your cmd ".... 2>&1" does this effect